# Call function once across multiple instances of a class

Tags: c++

I have been looking around for a while now and can't seem to find an answer to this.
So, if I have several instances of a class, how can I call a function only once from all instances of that class?
For example, if I have a function called `myFunc()` within a class called `myClass` and two instances of that class called `class1` and `class2`, then
`class1.myFunc()` should return 1,
`class2.myFunc()` should return 0, and
`class1.myFunc()` should return 0.

How would I do this?

```
class myClass{
public:
    myClass(){}
    int myFunc(){
        if (myFuncHasBeenCalled){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

myClass class1;
myClass class2;
class1.myFunc(); //would output 1
class2.myFunc(); //would output 0
class1.myFunc(); //would output 0
```

Comment: Are you aware of class-variables, created by using the `static` keyword?

Comment: Yes. I tried to use static variables but I may have done something wrong.

Comment: @Yunnosch I've deleted my comment. I misread the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by

- introducing a class variable, using `static` keyword for it in class declaration
- define the class variable in a (separate) code file, with initialisation
- check it inside the function, if 0 output 1 else 0
- increase (or set to non-zero) afterwards
- be careful, using synchronisation mechanisms, in case the calls might be from different contexts/threads/tasks/processes (whatever is applicable in your environment)

*(If you show your attempts with static variables and explain the problems you had, this could become more detailed.)*

Comment: I made a static boolean variable within the class which was false when the function was not called. But because it was static, I could not initialize it outside of a function. I needed to set this variable from the beginning so I defined it in the constructor. Because of that though, There would be no way for tell me to tell what it was originaly because it would be set to false for every instance of the class. Also, the variable was private.

Comment: Show your code by editing your question (add it, not replace the present code). See the "(spearate) **code** file" in my answer. Give me some 10 hours for reacting, I have to leave now.

Comment: I think it's better to use a static variable in the member function, as long as it doesn't need to be accessible outside of that function. Adding it to the class pollutes the interface and makes it harder to maintain a compatible ABI.

Comment: @Clearer Your point is valid. Without feedback by OP on how his attempts with static variables actually failed, I however prefer to keep the answer as accepted. OPs not very clear phrasing has room for a failure because of method-static-variables not being accessable from other methods. But to repeat, yes, minimising accesability of variables to the minimum is good.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options available: the idea is that you need to have some value that can be accessed independently of the instances of the class. `static` is the way to do this in all cases (except when it's not).

## Option one is best option -- static variable in member functions

The approach I would recommend is using a static variable in the member function; this avoids polluting the class itself and makes it easier for you to maintain a consistent ABI as well as a consistent API, across updates. It is very easy to reason about your code as you're not allowing anything else to access the variable.

Example:

```
struct S {
    int F() const {
         static int n = 1;
         if (n == 1) {
              n = 0;
              return 1;
         }

         return n;
    }
};
```

## Option two is bad option -- static variable in class

An alternative, which seems to be popular, is to keep a static member variable. This allows you do to the same thing as the previous example, but makes it harder to maintain the API and the ABI across upgrades. It also makes it harder to reason about your code and makes it easier to introduce bugs -- a static member variable is not much different from a global variable.

Example:

```
struct S {
    static int n;
    int F() const {
        if (n == 1) {
            n = 0;
            return 1;
        }

        return n;
    }
};

int S::n = 1;
```

## Option three is worst option -- global variables

The worst alternative is to use a global variable. I'm not going to give you an example of this -- don't do it. If you must do it anyway (you don't), declare your variables in an anonymous namespace in your `.cpp` file.

```
namespace {
    int n = 0
}
```

## Options four -- good option

Another approach is to use a *static member function*. This functions is fully independent of all instance of the class. The only difference in the implementation is that you add `static` to the function declaration -- otherwise, you can use the first two options. This won't be possible in all situations though.

## Caveats and other notes

If you need to use the variable to communicate state between two functions, you have to use one of the global options and cannot use a static variable in a member function.

In all cases, if you're not modifying the instance, you should mark your functions `const`.

<strike>You should really use [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) variables</strike>
You should use some sort of mechanism that guarantees that your code is threadsafe.

Comment: "You should really use `std::atomic` variables" - only if you need to. This is not at all always necessary. I would emphasize option four more. If it's not possible in this case, you're trying to do something weird and you should rethink your design.

Comment: @rubenvb I'm not disagreeing entirely. `std::atomic` has the nice property that it will allow you to write thread safe code more easily. You can do without it, but why take the chance?

Comment: if anything, using it by default gives you a false sense of security. In the end it may even end up killing performance.

Comment: @rubenvb to quote one of my former lecturers: "It's easy to get an answer that's fast and wrong". If your solution is broken, you're solution isn't fast.

Comment: to quote a famous person: if you use a bazooka to kill a rabbit, not much of it will be left for dinner. If this code is never going to see threads in any way, I disagree that using atomic variables is a good thing.

Comment: @rubenvb your code will see threads some day. If you're not prepared, the rabbit will bite your neck off.

Comment: part of my point was that using std::atomic does not magically make the rest of the code thread safe, and might lead to a false sense of security ("I did use atomic here so it should be ok"). `std::atomic` is not overhead free, nor is it always the correct solution to make your code thread safe at all.